# NSIS - Use offset with combination of !insertmacro

Tags: nsis

I was forced to use labels in my installer like this:

```
  IfFileExists "$INSTDIR\XX\*.*" XX_Found 0
      !insertmacro UnselectSection ${Section_XX}
  XX_Found:

  IfFileExists "$INSTDIR\YY\*.*" YY_Found 0
      !insertmacro UnselectSection ${Section_YY}
  YY_Found:
```

because these does not work:

```
  IfFileExists "$INSTDIR\XX\*.*" +2 0
      !insertmacro UnselectSection ${Section_XX}

  IfFileExists "$INSTDIR\YY\*.*" +2 0
      !insertmacro UnselectSection ${Section_YY}
```

Any proposal why? I think its because of !insertmacro statement but i could not find any information or workaround on the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use relative jumps on macros because a macro can contain more than one instruction. `!insertmacro` basically pastes the content of the `!macro` into your code during the first compiler phase.

I prefer using the LogicLib:

```
!include LogicLib.nsh
Section
${If} ${FileExists} "$InstDir\file.ext"
  !insertmacro ...
${EndIf}
SectionEnd
```

You can also use labels to jump over `!insertmacro`.

Comment: This make sence. I just used f${IfNot} instead o f${If}. Thanks!